# Android getting contacts photo from data.Email query

Tags: android, email, contacts, photo

I am making a autocomplete Field that queries contacts by Display name and Email. When someone clicks on the desired contact after the filtering that contact is added to a list with his email, display name and Picture if he has any.

So so far i have managed to do everything except to make the Photo appear. Here is how i run the query to get the email, display name, ID , and Photo ID.

```
    return mContent.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,
              PROJECTION, filter, null, null);
```

where projection is:

```
 PROJECTION = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
              ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
              ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
                Email.DATA
            };
```

This one does what i need and returns all the data. But one thing i noticed during debugging this issue is that the contact id is different than if you run the query against ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI for a specific display name for example.

For example the tests i have run where i get all the contacts by running the Contacts.CONTENT_URI gave me a contact with an image and Id of 152. However the query against the Email.CONTENT_URI gives me an id of 452 for the same contact (With same display name and email address). so when i try to get the Photo for a content uri containing the Id 452 it returns that the photo doesnt exist, but if i try to get the photo for 152 it works perfectly.

What is causing this issue? how do i get the correct User ID? Is there any relational query that i can maybe run to get a contact ID, or maybe a correct way to get it with the help of this one.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I found this digging around old code. Might be helpful to anyone.

So the full query:

```
String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
            Email.DATA, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID };

                String order = " CASE WHEN " + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " NOT LIKE '%@%' THEN 1" + " ELSE 2 END, "
                        + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE";
                String filter = Email.DATA + " NOT LIKE '' ) GROUP BY ( " + Email.DATA;
```

then its

`getContentResolver().query( Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, filter, null, order);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to access the photo of a contact, you need to specify the contact photo URI, for example using this method:

```
public Uri getContactPhotoUri(long contactId) {
    Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(photoUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    return photoUri;
}
```

But for contactId you must use:

```
String id = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID;
long contactId = Long.parseLong(id);
```

Please note that a common error is to use `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID` instead `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID`

I hope that can help you.

Comment: It is actually ContactsContract.Contacts._ID to be used.

Comment: I don't get the part of "id" and that you've parsed it to long (which will crash since it's not a long).

Answer (score 1):

You should use RAW_CONTACT_ID in the query. For ex, there can be two different contacts i.e. different RAW_CONTACT_ID for a single CONTACT_ID.

Comment: i tried to use RAW_CONTACT_ID and But it gives me the same result as this one... same id. so i assume the table contains the raw id and the query returns it to me. but when i build the uri for the contacts photo i still get the same uri as before and same result... As far as i can tell this query preforms some kind of join db operation since the Email table doesn't contain some of this params.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can take a look at this blog post in the example there they query all contacts, email addresses and the contact photo
http://blog.app-solut.com/2011/03/working-with-the-contactscontract-to-query-contacts-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

best code will be

```
Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Id);

    Bitmap photoBitmap;
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    InputStream is = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, photoUri);

    photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

it works for all