# how to get photo from contacts?

Tags: java, android

I want to get photo from contacts, if some contacts don't have photo to return default photo(just silhouette), how can I do that?
Thanks in advance,
Wolf.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332333/android-problem-getting-contacts-photo-from-data-email-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html) to get the picture for the specified contact.

Full example from the above documentation link:

```
public InputStream openDisplayPhoto(long contactId) {
     Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
     Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
     try {
         AssetFileDescriptor fd =
             getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");
         return fd.createInputStream();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: do I have to put xml like this :
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ivSlika"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:clickable="true" >
  </ImageView>

Comment: because I want to populate listview with contacts names and photos.