# How can I add the joined contact image in contacts (android)?

Tags: android, contacts

I am exporting the contact from my app and I want to add the joined contact icon with exporting contact as below image like google icon with my custom icon.
if there is example or any one know how to do that.

Please let me know.

Thank you
[image].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332333/android-problem-getting-contacts-photo-from-data-email-query

Comment: hi thank you but i am asking for joined contact image not contact image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got it. this is possible using if I create contacts [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#SyncAdapters)

with the help of

```
   <ContactsDataKind
    android:mimeType="MIMEtype"
    android:icon="icon_resources" <!-- Put the icon here -->
    android:summaryColumn="column_name"
    android:detailColumn="column_name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
<ContactsDataKind
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:mimeType="MIMEtype"
    android:summaryColumn="data2"
    android:detailColumn="data3"
    android:detailSocialSummary="true">             
</ContactsDataKind>

<ContactsDataKind
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:mimeType="MIMEtype"
    android:summaryColumn="data2"
    android:detailColumn="data3"
    android:detailSocialSummary="true">             
</ContactsDataKind>
```